# Is there a freeware program for databases similar to Microsoft Access?

Tags: software-recommendation, database, korganizer

Is there a freeware program anyone can recommend that is comparable to Microsoft Access? I need to store a lot of data and want to access it quickly by category and query.

Comment: You can try LibreOffice **Base** that is part of the LibreOffice suite.

Answer (score 0):

### LibreOffice Base

[image: LibreOfficeBase]

**Reference**: [LibreOffice Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/)

### Apache OpenOffice base

[image: Apache Openoffice base]

**Reference**: [Openoffice](https://www.openoffice.org/)

Comment: Check out https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-access/?platform=linux for a long list

Comment: I don't use GUI for managing databases ;)